# How Can I set path for generate sourcemap files by autoprefixer-cli or postcss

Tags: css, command-line-interface, postcss, autoprefixer

I want to generate sourcemap file to defined path by CLI.
for example below.

## by autoprefixer-cli

```
> autoprefixer-cli css/style.css -o css/style.css --map SET_PATH_FOR_MAPFILE
```

above command is working, but ignore SET_PATH_FOR_MAPFILE.
it just generated sourcemap file in the defined output(-o) path.

---

## by postcss

```
> postcss --replace css/style.css --use autoprefixer --map SET_PATH_FOR_MAPFILE
```

above command is also working, but ignore SET_PATH_FOR_MAPFILE.
it just replaced to defined css file(path).

---

In conclusion, I didn't get the output I wanted.

```
// expected output
css/style.css
SET_PATH_FOR_MAPFILE/style.prefixed.css.map

// actual output
css/style.css
css/style.css.map
```

How Can I generate sourcemap files defined path by CLI?

Answer (score 1):

The PostCSS CLI plugin does not offer the ability to define a source map path, so I'm afraid you're out of luck there. The options include;

1. no flags at all, sourcemap is inlined in output CSS file by default
2. `--map`, outputs a sourcemap in the same root as your output CSS
3. `--no-map`, outputs CSS without any source map.

More info can be find on their [GitHub page](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-cli).